# Sklearn tree classification on catogorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

im trying to create a simple classification with tree classifier for disease symptoms. i have tried it using sklearn tree classifier. 
it gives the following error. both my code and error is there.
Any suggestion ?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
symptoms = [['flat face','poor moro','hypotonia'],['small head','small jaw','overlapping fingers'], ['small eyes','cleft lip','cleft palate']]
lables = [['Trisomy 21'],['Trisomy 18'],['Trisomy 13']]
classify = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classify = classify.fit(symptoms, lables)
```

**it gives the following error**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-0f2c956618c2> in <module>
      4 lables = [['Trisomy 21'],['Trisomy 18'],['Trisomy 13']]
      5 classify = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 6 classify = classify.fit(symptoms, lables)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    799             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    800             check_input=check_input,
--> 801             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    802         return self
    803 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    114         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    115         if check_input:
--> 116             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    117             y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    118             if issparse(X):

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'flat face'
```

Comment: Use one hot encoding to convert these

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `label encoder` for encoding your string values. The following will work for your requirement:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
symptoms = [['flat face','poor moro','hypotonia'],['small head','small jaw','overlapping fingers'], ['small eyes','cleft lip','cleft palate']]
lables = [['Trisomy 21'],['Trisomy 18'],['Trisomy 13']]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(symptoms), pd.DataFrame(lables)], axis=1)
x_cols = ['sym1', 'sym2', 'sym3']
y_col = 'target'
df.columns = x_cols + [y_col]
df = df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
classify = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classify.fit(df[x_cols].values, df[y_col].values)
```